# Multisite with subfolders- can't access main site- Error establishing a database connection

Tags: multisite, database

I guess the issue might be somewhere in the database with ip instead of the domain, but I can't access the `database`.

I can access the `subfolder` site mydomain.com/site, but can't access the main mydomain.com, as it is showing `Error establishing a database connection`.

What could cause this issue and can someone please help fixing it? :)